# Spring Boot REST controller validation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a working spring REST web-service and i wanted to add validation for handling different scenarios, i have tried implementing if clauses in my service class and that did not seem efficient one issue i am currently having is whenever i add a new record by sending an existing primary key(auto generated id) JPA seems to update the existing record but when i send non existing id a new record is created but not using an id i sent, an auto generated is used. Here is the code:

Author

```
@PostMapping("/authors")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String addAnAuthor(@Valid @RequestBody Author author){
    return  authorService.addAuthor(author);
}
```

Author service

```
public String addAuthor(Author author) {

    if(authorRepository.existsByFirstNameAndLastName(author.getFirstName(),author.getLastName())){
        return "Author or Author ID Already Exists";
    }

    else{
        authorRepository.save(author);
        return "Created";
    }


}
```

If i send a request without an ID same will be created, but if i send next one with existing id and different first name (to pass validation on first name) it will overwrite an existing record. post man request:

```
 {
       "firstName": "Jane",
       "lastName": "Doe"
 }
 {
       "id":25,
       "firstName": "John",
       "lastName": "Doe"
 }
 {
       "id":85,
       "firstName": "Mike",
       "lastName": "Doe"
 }
```

The first one will create a new record and if we assume it's id is 25 and send the second one, the first record will be overwritten, for the third one a new record will be created but with id 26 (auto incremented) ignoring the forwarded id.

I think there is a validation of some sort inside there, i am wondering if i could leverage this and why is it accepting id if it is an auto generated value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the flow you are using:-

Consider this:-

```
_______________________________
| ID   | firstname  | lastname |
--------------------------------
| 1    | john       | cena     |
--------------------------------
| 2    | john       | johnson  |
--------------------------------
```

The two users already are there now you are thinking if you are updating the user with `1` on the basis of only firstname and lastname without id, then when your flow is getting called you are actually passing (**example john and mayer as firstname and lastname respectively**) and when the function existsByFirstNameAndLastName() is called, you are actually passing the value like **`existsByFirstNameAndLastName("john","mayer")`** which will definitely not exist and thus causing a new save rather than update(**the code for which does not exist already**)

```
--------------------------------
| 3    | john       | mayer    |
--------------------------------
```

and an entry like above created

```
authorRepository.existsByFirstNameAndLastName(author.getFirstName(),author.getLastName())
```

You are using it to get the `Author` based on new(**it will always be new as per your code**) `firstname` and `lastname` values which have been updated in the request you are sending(you or your user thinks as if it has updated the values), and in your case the author will definitely not exist.

My suggestions:-

Have separate methods for create and update flows like below:-

***For Creating the Author***:-

**Controller Method**

```
@PostMapping("/authors")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String addAnAuthor(@Valid @RequestBody Author author){
    return authorService.addAuthor(author);
}
```

**Service Method**

```
public String addAuthor(Author author) {
    if(authorRepository.existsByFirstNameAndLastName(author.getFirstName(),author.getLastName())){
        return "Author or Author ID Already Exists";
    }
    else{
        authorRepository.save(author);
        return "Created";
    }
}
```

***For Updating the Author***:-

**Controller Method**

```
@PutMapping("/authors")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) // you can have this changed as per your convention in the applications, you may use HttpStatus.ACCEPTED(202), HttpStatus.CREATED(201), HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT(204) or HttpStatus.OK(200)
public String updateAnAuthor(@Valid @RequestBody Author author){
    return authorService.updateAuthor(author);
}
```

**Service Method**

```
public String updateAuthor(Author author) {
    if(authorRepository.existsByIdAndFirstNameAndLastName(author.getId(),author.getFirstName(),author.getLastName())){
        return "Author or Author ID Already Exists";
    }
    else{
        Author existingAuthor = authorRepository.findByID(author.getID());// you will have to check as per your spring hibernate versions, as this will vary as per versions
        existingAuthor.setFirstName(author.getFirstName()); // updating the FirstName field
        existingAuthor.setLastName(author.getLastName()); // updating the LastName field
        authorRepository.update(existingAuthor); // use appropriate method here it could be merge or update, depends on the type of configuration
        return "Updated";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, implementing your above suggestion it still wouldn't prevent unintended user from updating a record by using @PostMapping and passing an existing user's id and new details.

Comment: that will always create, as in the method there `addAuthor()` is being called which further calls the method  `callsauthorRepository.existsByFirstNameAndLastName()` and this method only has firstname and lastname as arguments, we are not passing id.

Comment: check the update, added some code to `updateAuthor()` it will first fetch the author based on the id and do some getter setter and then update

Comment: Sorry for back and forth i am still having an issue where addAuthor is updating record if existing author id is passed https://ibb.co/eN6GfS Before sending request and https://ibb.co/gWpxn7 after sending request

Comment: make it conditional for the flows, use addAnAuthor for adding and use updateAnAuthor for update

Comment: are you having same page for create and update? if yes then I can give a scenario for that also

Comment: I am building a rest webservice, no UI.

Comment: then I suggest use two flows POST for create and PUT for update, this is always a better approach

Comment: Yes that is correct, but what if malicious users try to use this opening, by not following the POST and PUT specifications?

Comment: your service layer code in POST type won't even use ID even if supplied so not a problem for malicious users, so it will always create a new user, and malicious aspect will even go more messy in the case of using a single method for both PUT and POST, tracking on same method for both flows?

Comment: `addOrUpdateAnAuthor(Controller)` -> `addOrUpdateAnAuthorService(At Service Layeer)`{ // will grow up to super messy and cumbersome } -> calling different repository methods here which could be get, create, update, etc

Comment: Thanks. I think i have something else causing this issue, if you have seen my earlier link to screenshots it is exactly doing what it wasn't supposed to do "service layer code in POST type won't even use ID even if supplied"

Comment: your screen shots were not opening, and your architecture should be loosely coupled for different flows, and tightly scoping them to a single flow is not a good suggestion from me :-)

Comment: I am not trying to achieve addAuthor and updateAuthor in one request. I am trying for addAuthor to only Add a new Author and updateAuthor to only update an existing Author using POST and PUT respectively, however addAuthor still allows a record to be updated if provided with an existing Author id and i am trying to eliminate that.

Comment: no no you are not getting the point, it will always create not update a new entry is getting created because the method `.existsByFirstNameAndLastName` has updated(not updated actually but new) values of the author which are like a fresh author only, which is not there in the Database at all

Comment: please see updated answer in the beginning of the answer

Comment: I feel If I could have explained you using some pen and paper

Comment: Lool, yes i feel dumb and i wish i could show you what is happening with my database records, it is not creating a new one as for your example sending  |1    | john       | mayer  will actually replace john cena to john mayer (i tried it) :-(. Thanks for your time, i'll accept ur suggestion as an answer and try somewhere else.

Comment: yeap anyways just keep on exploring, you have to have clarity of the flow, to keep going, Happy coding